# Missing ribbon on custom web resources CRM 2016 issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2016

We have faced with strange behavior in CRM 2016 SP1.
When we open some entity with help of full url and then go to custom web resource page (added via sitemap (web resource, url etc.)) our ribbon suddenly disappears. Please, watch GIF below.

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

The resulted state of introduced GIF is mentioned below:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Site Map customized part (SubArea with Id="nav_pipeline"):

```
<SiteMap IntroducedVersion="7.0.0.0">
  <Area Id="SFA" ResourceId="Area_Sales" DescriptionResourceId="Sales_Description" Icon="/_imgs/sales_24x24.gif" ShowGroups="true" IntroducedVersion="7.0.0.0">
    <Group Id="MyWork" ResourceId="Group_MyWork" DescriptionResourceId="My_Work_Description" ToolTipResourseId="My_Work_ToolTip" IntroducedVersion="7.0.0.0">
      <SubArea Id="nav_dashboards" ResourceId="Homepage_Dashboards" DescriptionResourceId="Dashboards_Description" ToolTipResourseId="Dashboards_ToolTip" Icon="/_imgs/area/18_home.gif" Url="/workplace/home_dashboards.aspx" GetStartedPanePath="Dashboards_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Dashboards_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Dashboards_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Dashboards_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" DefaultDashboard="2701de60-8f2a-48a4-8262-4a35ca7441fa" IntroducedVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      <SubArea Id="nav_personalwall" ResourceId="Whats_New_Label" DescriptionResourceId="Whats_New_Description" ToolTipResourseId="Whats_New_ToolTip" Icon="$webresource:msdyn_/Images/Wall_16.png" OutlookShortcutIcon="$webresource:msdyn_/Images/Wall_16.png" AvailableOffline="false" Url="$webresource:msdyn_/PersonalWall.htm?data=HideUserProfile%3D0" GetStartedPanePath="Dashboards_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Dashboards_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Dashboards_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Dashboards_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" IntroducedVersion="7.0.0.0">
        <Privilege Entity="post" Privilege="Read" />
      </SubArea>
      <SubArea Id="nav_activities" DescriptionResourceId="Activities_SubArea_Description" ToolTipResourseId="Activities_SubArea_ToolTip" Url="/_root/homepage.aspx?etc=4200" Entity="activitypointer" GetStartedPanePath="Activities_Web_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Activities_Web_Admin_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Activities_Outlook_User_Visor.html" GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Activities_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" IntroducedVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      <SubArea Icon="$webresource:msdyn_/Images/likeIcon.png" Id="nav_pipeline" Url="$webresource:msdyn_/FirstRunContent.1033.htm" Description="Pipeline View" Title="Pipeline" AvailableOffline="false" PassParams="false" Client="Web" />
    </Group>
    ...
</Area>
</SiteMap>
```

Comment: Whats your site map configuration?

Comment: @JamesWood, Site Map was not changed except of the part with custom web resource (see UPDATE 2)

Answer (score 0):

May be that understood something in wrong way but check screenshot I took from your example. I'm pretty sure that ribbon is still there:

[image]

Comment: No, you've misunderstood it, you got the starting screenshot of the gif, not the last one.

Comment: I haven't experienced such kind of issue but I would suggest to open debugger and load your webresource as you are doing it. It is possible that you can see in profiler that something went wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error neither in Network nor in console and web resource was reached successfully. Could you please show me, how do you try to reproduce this issue? Maybe also as a gif? It reproduces in our crm 2015 and brand new crm 2016 every time when we open record with help of "Pop Out" button and then go to Site Map button with custom web resource.

Comment: I meant that I haven't embedded webresource to CRM Sitemap since 2011 times. That's why I haven't experienced such kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just wild guess, since this issue should be debugged carefully, but it seems to be you're loading web resource to the wrong target.

Subribbon and content are probably in separate iFrames, and it is hosted in another iFrame where your web resource is loaded by default. To avoid this you will need explicitly load it content's iFrame. Most likely it should be achieved by setting `target` HTML attribute.